# Model Hypothesis testing using R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, forecasting, model

I am currently trying to test a hypothesis in R using two mutual funds that have almost identical alpha values over a 5 year period.

here's the model. I was wondering if anybody could give me a good starting point to do this?
[image]

Comment: you can use something like linearHypothesis in car, http://web.pdx.edu/~joel8/resources/ConceptualPresentationResources/LinearHypothesisTesting.pdf, i am not so familiar with alpha or how your model is set up

Comment: if you can provide some code or example, can help u w that